# Create a fishnet using lat/lon table text file

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python-2.6

I have a text file with lat/lon table values and want to use this information to generate a fishnet using python. Any heads up would be deeply appreciative. Also please point to if this has been already addressed.

Answer (score 2):

If your fishnet is evenly spaced, you can use the [Create Fishnet geoprocessing tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) in ArcMap to accomplish this.

If you have a more complicated fishnet, you can use the [basic geometry writing functionality of ArcPy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Writing_geometries/002z0000001v000000/) to create a fishnet of points, polylines or polygons.

Comment: It is evenly spaced. I want to do it in python script to have it as a workflow for future reference. The use of fishnet in script is detailed in resource help but the use of text file in script is what bugging me?

Comment: In text file there are two entries lat and lon. I want to use these to generate fishnet in script

Comment: To read and write files, consult the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html).  The [fishnet tool help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) has Python code snippets that can get you started.